# How to get 'Keep UV and edit mode mesh in sync' UV vertices

Tags: uv, edit-mode, vertices

I'm trying to switch from `Keep UV and edit mode mesh in sync`, but keep the UV selection. After switching sync off, I also trigger `mesh.select_all` to make it visible from UV editor, but there are two different selections for both non sync and sync mode.

The selection I did before entering sync mode is still there after making a different selection and then exiting sync mode.

How could I access the sync mode vertices to get the selection and make it the same in non sync mode?